# Blinking TextBlock.Text in Silverlight 4 Button

Tags: .net, silverlight, animation, button, blend

I am currently working on a Kiosk application in Silverlight 4.  A user can add items to a cart and check out all using the Kiosk.  When going from page to page I want to incorporate a button that has a blinking "outer glow", if you will, on the background of the button as well as the text of the button.  I could do this with images but the text needs to be dynamic and I'd like to be able to create this as a template to be called on other buttons later on.

I wanted to start off by just trying to get the text blinking within my button.

```
          <Button Name="AddItemButton" Height="110" Click="AddItemButton_Click" Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRound1}">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FlashMe">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="AddItemButtonTextBlock">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Button.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="Images/bg-greengradient.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="AddItemButtonTextBlock" Text="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>

            </Button>
```

As you can see, my Button.Content is a grid with 2 items in it.  I have an Image and a TextBlock.  The TextBlock should be controlled by my FlashMe storyboard but on the code behind, I get an error trying to use FlashMe.Begin();  It's almost like I'm not allowed to use a storyboard on the content of a button. Any ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Specifically?

Comment: removed the codebhind FlashMe.Begin(); but still getting the error System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: if it's just above code without any code behind it should be working fine, the error must come from something else.

Answer (score 0):

had something to do with the style. removed style, works fine. resolved.